# Minimal font file which contains only the text required

Tags: css, font-face

I currently have a webpage which uses 2 font files and a lot of images

- i have optimized the images to an extent, but my page still loads very slow,
  next option was to optimize the font files
- I am using Diavlo font for the logo , the size of the font file is 55kb.

i have read that Google fonts by specifying a text= value in your font request URL.

This allows Google to return a font file that's optimized for your request. In some cases, this can reduce the size of the font file by up to 90%.

```
@font-face{
font-family:'diavlo';
src: url('diavlo_medium_ii_37-webfont.eot');
src: url('diavlo_medium_ii_37-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype') ,
                      url('diavlo_medium_ii_37-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}

 I did not find Diavlo in Google Fonts.
```

Google fonts

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=Hello
```

So is there a way i can provide only the text i require to get a minimal .ttf file

and should i include either **.woff** file or **.ttf** or both.

Comment: how long does it take to download the page?

Comment: You can use any font you have the permission to using [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), but since the _text_ is drawn using canvas, I'm not sure how it could affect your page load time.

Comment: it takes 7.92s to load and the diavlo font is taking 6s(55kb)

Answer (score 1):

If you know which characters you need specifically, you can use Font Squirel's [@font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator/) and specify only which characters you want, this is the only way i know of doing it. This will generate the needed font files, with only the characters you want.

**Note:** make sure you have it set to expert mode